# Regular expressions for strings not containing specific substring

Tags: regular-language

What could be the regular expression for - ***All words that do not have the substring `baa`*** for alphabet set =`{a,b}`?

Is it:

```
a* ((aa) * b *)?
```

Can a string of length 2 be acceptable for the above condition to hold?

Comment: In fact, any string of length 2 is in this language as it may not contain a three-character substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a*(ba?)*
```

At start, it can go with arbitrarily many `a`'s, but once a `b` has been introduced, not more than a single isolated `a` is allowed to appear anywhere hereupon.

Comment: Then how can I generate ***abba*** from your given reg-ex?

Comment: a* for a;
ba? for b;
ba? for ba

Comment: thank you! Can the context free grammar for this reg-ex be: `S->AB , A->aA | null, B-> bBa | bB | null?`

Comment: No, bbaa is in this grammar.

Comment: Is this right : S-> AB ;  A->aA| ^ ; B-> bB | baB| ^ ?

Comment: Does `^` denote empty string? Looks like it is.

Comment: Yes it's null symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
a*(b+(ba))*
```

By grammar, once `b` reached, there can be many `b` occurrences or if there is an `a` after `b`, it must end or follow by `b` or by `ba`.